# Vue JS displaying a block on hovering over a certain picture

Tags: javascript, vue.js, optimization, vuejs2

I have four pictures when you hover over one of these pictures, certain content appears, for example, if you hover the mouse over the first picture, a green block appears when you hover over the second picture, a blue block appears, and so on, the problem is that the logic that I have implemented looks like nightmarish

Here is a [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-pond-b47d9), you can see the logic on codesandbox, I want to know if it is possible to somehow optimize the logic to make it more readable and simple

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="girls_gallery">
      <div class="girls_gallery_content">
        <div>
          <div class="g_gallery_title_container">
            <h1>Hover Image</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="girls_list">
            <div class="girls_container">
              <img
                style="width: 200px; height: 200px"
                @mouseover="mouseOver1"
                @mouseout="mouseout"
                src="https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/500px/983794168.jpg"
                alt="Snow"
              />
            </div>

            <div class="girls_container">
              <img
                style="width: 200px; height: 200px"
                @mouseover="mouseOver2"
                @mouseout="mouseout"
                src="https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/500px/983794168.jpg"
                alt="Snow"
              />
            </div>

            <div class="girls_container">
              <img
                style="width: 200px; height: 200px"
                @mouseover="mouseOver3"
                @mouseout="mouseout"
                src="https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/500px/983794168.jpg"
                alt="Snow"
              />
            </div>

            <div class="girls_container">
              <img
                style="width: 200px; height: 200px"
                @mouseover="mouseOver4"
                @mouseout="mouseout"
                src="https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/500px/983794168.jpg"
                alt="Snow"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top: 50px">
      <div
        style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background: red"
        v-show="img1"
        key="img1"
      ></div>
      <div
        style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background: green"
        v-show="img2"
        key="img1"
      ></div>
      <div
        style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background: blue"
        v-show="img3"
        key="img1"
      ></div>
      <div
        style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background: orange"
        v-show="img4"
        key="img1"
      ></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",

  data() {
    return {
      img1: false,
      img2: false,
      img3: false,
      img4: false,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    mouseOver1: function () {
      this.img1 = true;
    },
    mouseOver2: function () {
      this.img2 = true;
    },
    mouseOver3: function () {
      this.img3 = true;
    },
    mouseOver4: function () {
      this.img4 = true;
    },
    mouseout: function () {
      this.img1 = false;
      this.img2 = false;
      this.img3 = false;
      this.img4 = false;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it hasn't "clicked" yet with regards on how vue is supposed to work. Check this as an example for reference:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-dream-237l0?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Basically what you want to do is to render your component content based on component data. Thus you create a data object that holds the information required for your logic.

Comment: I really like the simplicity of your code, I want to apologize for the earlier, but the problem is that when I hover over the picture I would like to display the components, you might notice that in my code on the sandbox I had four commented components I need on mouse hover to display these components on the picture, I would like to once again apologize for not saying this earlier

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is add `position: relative` to `girls_container`. Then move your color block into the `<div class="girls_container">`.

Next, add the following to your color blocks

```css
z-index: 9999;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

Move `@mouseover` and `@mouseout` to the `girls_container`.

```html
<div class="girls_list">
  <div
    class="girls_container"
    style="position: relative"
    @mouseover="mouseOver1"
    @mouseout="mouseout"
  >
    <img
      ref="img1"
      style="width: 200px; height: 200px"
      src="https://www.gettyimages.com/gi-resources/images/500px/983794168.jpg"
      alt="Snow"
    />
    <div
      style="
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background: red;
        z-index: 9999;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
      "
      v-show="img1"
      key="img1"
      ref="img-block1"
    ></div>
  </div>
```

[Example on Code SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-glade-n1vpb?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)